# .NET compact framework signature drawing GUI element

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Is there a way to allow a user to draw with their stylus (a signature in my case) in a Windows Form? Something like `InkCanvas` in WPF.

I don't think I can use WPF in a compact framework project, or maybe I'm setting it up wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there isnt any control to do that, you could do this manualy by catching the stylus events and drawing pixels when they occur.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use WPF in the Compact Framework, but OpenNETCF do a [Mobile Ink Library](http://www.opennetcf.com/OpenSource/MobileInk.ocf) which is open source. This library allows you to make a standard control on your form ink-aware and capture the data.